# Unmount SSHFS from Nautilus (with umount)

Tags: mount, nautilus, sshfs, umount, fuse

I can mount an SSHFS like this:

```
sshfs -o idmap=user SSH_HOSTNAME:/ ~/mountpoint
```

Now it's nicely displayed in Nautilus like a removable device with an eject button. On clicking that button though, I get a permission error:

> **Unable to unmount “foo”**
>
> umount: /home/bytecommander/mountpoint: Permission denied

Same if I directly run `umount ~/mountpoint`.

I know I can unmount it using `fusermount -u ~/mountpoint` or I could use `sudo umount ~/mountpoint`, but I want to get it working in Nautilus (without elevated privileges), which seems to be using `umount` internally.

How can I achieve this?

PS: I have read somewhere that I should add my user to the `fuse` group, but there is no such group on my 16.04 system and the mounting works anyway, so I don't think it's needed.

Comment: try running with elevated privileges.

Comment: @AndrewShum That's not really an option, as I don't want to run Nautilus in admin mode just to unmount an SSHFS I own myself. This question is only about getting the unmount from Nautilus working, I know how I can do it from the commandline.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be known bug of GVFS:

- [bug 607706 on GNOME bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=607706)
- [bug 254171 on LaunchPad](https://launchpad.net/bugs/254171).

Note: my Ubuntu 16.04 has `fuse` group, I'm member of this group, but Caja has the same problem (it's [bug 1763033](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/caja/+bug/1763033)).